# Patodi's Paper: Curvature and Eigenforms of the laplace operator details and explanations

Tags: analysis, riemannian-geometry, tensors, p-laplacian

I am currently studying Analysis on manifolds for my thesis. I am looking for some references about the McKean-Singer conjecture and Patodi's proof. I read with much attention to detail his paper: Curvature and the eigenforms of the laplace operator. However I am having difficulty over some of the arguments. I would like to kindly request some references about this specific paper, for example some extra details or maybe if this is contained in a book. Thanks in advance.